# RSS memory equivalent in cgroup v2

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, cgroups

I'm trying to write a script which reports a Docker container's memory consumption. I found out I can get these values by reading the cgroup files.

One of the metrics I'm interested in is the RSS memory (memory.rss) from [cgroup v1](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt). However, I found that it is not directly available in [cgroup v2](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html#memory-interface-files), which my container is using.

I'm not well-versed in the kernel memory types. In cgroup v1, `memory.rss` is defined as "# of bytes of anonymous and swap cache memory (includes transparent hugepages)". In cgroup v2, I think it is equal to the sum of

- anon (Amount of memory used in anonymous mappings such as brk(), sbrk(), and mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)
- shmem (Amount of cached filesystem data that is swap-backed, such as tmpfs, shm segments, shared anonymous mmap()s)

Am I right? or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

`/sys/fs/cgroup/memory.current` is an equivalent of RSS for a container that uses cgroup v2. The path can be used to read container memory consumption from within the container.

`memory.current` includes all resident pages for the cgroup - anonymous mappings, file and so on. `memory.stat` breaks down `memory.current` into different memory types used by the cgroup.

If you want to monitor RSS outside of container, the path to a container's cgroup in the root namespace may be different depending on cgroup driver:

```
/sys/fs/cgroup/docker/<longid>/ with cgroupfs driver
/sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/docker-<longid>.scope/ with systemd driver
/sys/fs/cgroup/<parent-cgroup>.slice/docker-<longid>.scope/ with systemd driver with `--parent-cgroup` option
```

Comment: Cgroup v2 `memory.current` is an equivalent of cgroup v1 `memory.usage_in_bytes`. Cgroup v1 `memory.stat:rss` actually should be named 'rss_anon' or 'mapped_anon' because it accounts only anonoymous part of resident memory. Cgroup v2 has field `memory.stat:anon` which is an exact equivalent of v1 `memory.stat:total_rss` (i.e. includes all nested cgroups).